# Numerically solving a system of partial integro-differential equations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, pde, numerical-analysis, integral-equations

Given the following system of **partial integro-differential equations**
$$ \frac{dX(t)}{dt}=\Lambda-\mu X(t)-\beta X(t)Z(t),\\
\frac{\partial Y(t,\omega)}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial Y(t,\omega)}{\partial \omega}=-\delta(\omega) Y(t,\omega),\\
\frac{dZ(t)}{dt}=-\gamma Z(t)+(N-Z(t))\int^{\infty}_{0}\kappa (\omega)Y(t,\omega)d\omega $$
with the **boundary condition** 
$$Y(t,0)=\beta X(t)Z(t)$$ and
**initial conditions** 
$$X(0)=X_{0},Y(0,\omega)= \sigma(\omega),Z(0)=Z_{0} $$ 
where all parameters $\Lambda, \mu, \beta, \delta(\omega), \gamma, N, \kappa(\omega), X_{0},Z_{0}$ are positive.

**How does one numerically compute a solution for this on Matlab?**

**Note** : I was asked to repost this question in scicomp.se -

[Numerically solving a system of partial integro-differential equations in Matlab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365355/numerically-solving-a-system-of-partial-integro-differential-equations-in-matlab)